# Are there good Q&A sites other than Stack Exchange for English?

Tags: support

This question might seem to be rather offensive to this site, so kindly pardon me.

Since I sometimes have English related questions which are prohibited to ask here,
so could someone teach me if there is or not, and if there is, what are them?

I have seen one site and I used it, but since I changed my PC, I put the bookmark off the list with my mistake.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: *"This question might seem to be rather offensive to this site"* — Definitely not! SE was never meant to cover all the related questions on a topic, not even all the useful ones. Its model works best for an exchange between people who are already well-versed in a topic (imagine coworkers asking each other for hints on the next line of code), and therefore, for example, questions about getting started with a topic, while being valid, get closed as "too broad". That said, there are forums like Quora and Wordreference AFAIK but their lax take on moderation sometimes impedes learning.

Comment: If you Google around with an English-related question you do encounter a few forums with varying quality. ([exmple](https://www.google.com/search?q=if+vs+in+case&oq=if+vs+in+case&aqs=chrome..69i57.3602j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)) but I find that in such cases tutorial pages of more reputable sources (universities etc.) are more reliable.

Comment: Yahoo! Answers will take just about any question on just about any topic. There is also [this site](https://www.englishforums.com/) for questions about English.

Comment: @J.R. With so much appreciation. I haven't known the U.S Yaoo! has Q&A site since its beginning. What an :::hole I am. And it seems it is a robust system. Thanks.  By the way, what I am looking for currently and pinpointing is some word -something - forum which Natun Taggy once briefly mentioned...

Comment: Also consider that the Stack Exchange chat is not constrained to the same format and topics as the main sites (EL&U chat is currently discussing the Notre Dame de Paris fire). While proofreading a paragraph or asking for transcriptions still won't be appreciated, you can pose questions if looking for quick, informal responses. Learners are welcome on both the ELL and EL&U chatrooms; the former is obviously more sensitive to their needs, but the latter is more active.