# Why don't mods delete this comment?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged [**this comment in Japanese**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4972/are-there-good-qa-sites-other-than-stack-exchange-for-english) because the comment is written in Japanese, but no moderators deleted so far.

Isn't this against the answers to [**this question?**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5014/can-one-ask-questions-in-a-different-language)

Or is it because the writer is a mod of Japanese SE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It wasn’t deleted until 6 hours after you flagged it because the mod team are volunteers and aren’t here 24 hours a day every day. As soon as a moderator saw it, it was removed and your flag marked “helpful”. Your response to that comment, which started with “Who the hell are you?”, violates the code of conduct and was also removed.

You are expected to be respectful of everyone regardless of their behavior. If you can’t be respectful, don’t post. Just flag it and wait for a moderator to take care of it.